# Delphi Tchart x and y values in zoomed rectangle

Tags: delphi, series, teechart

I have a tchart series that contains 5000 points from a data base.
I can zoom in on a particular section of the data with the mouse.
I wish to copy only the x and y values that are visible in the subset to the clipboard (or text file).
I can easiy access the entire series,  however I have not been able to figure out how to access only
the data in the zoomed rectangle.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance
Arthur

Answer (score 0):

The series X index range in the zoomed rectangle is [`FirstValueIndex`..`LastValueIndex`].

Note : They are only accessible after the values are displayed.

A value of -1 means that the whole range is to be used. [0..Count-1]

Update :

And if you want to clip on Y values as well, then step through above indexes and check against leftAxis.Minimum and leftAxis.Maximum.

Answer (score 0):

If you can represent any point from the series as a `TPoint` structure (e.g. with the help of the `Point()` function) and the view area as a `TRect` (e.g. using `Rect()`), you will be able to use the `PtInRect()` function to test whether the point is within the zoomed rectangle:

```
if PtInRect(ZoomedRect, ChartPoint) then ...
```

References:

- [`TPoint`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Types.TPoint)
- [`Point()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Types.Point)
- [`TRect`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Types.TRect)
- [`Rect()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Types.Rect)
- [`PtInRect()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Types.PtInRect)

Answer (score 0):

This was discussed [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=11361&p=48204&hilit=points%20selection#p48204). Hope suggestions here are useful for you.